# Copy data from table and insert in different SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two databases

- `databaseone`
- `databasetwo`

and I have a similar table in the database, name of the table is `tableemployeedetails`.

In my `databaseone`, I have 500 columns in the table `tableemployeedetails`.

In my `databasetwo`, I have 10 columns in the table `tableemployeedetails`.

I cannot use `insert into select query` because I want to insert the data into different database.

What is the best way to do this in my situation?

I just want to merge `tableemployeedetails` in both the databases

Comment: Why can't you insert into different database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    insert into databasetwo..tableemployeedetails
    SELECT * FROM databaseone..tableemployeedetails  A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM databasetwo..tableemployeedetails B
                      WHERE A.COLUMN=B.COLUMN
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If both databases has different records then you need two insert statements as below. If they have same then you need to prefer which database records are latest and then write an update in addition to the below insert.

```
insert into databasetwo..tableemployeedetails
SELECT * FROM databaseone..tableemployeedetails  d1
    left join databasetwo..tableemployeedetails d2 on A.PKKEY=B.PKKEY
    where d2.PKKEY is null

insert into databaseone..tableemployeedetails
SELECT * FROM databasetwo..tableemployeedetails  d2
    left join databaseone..tableemployeedetails d1 on A.PKKEY=B.PKKEY
    where d1.PKKEY is null
```